# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

Unable to resolve the error. I'm getting two different errors

1. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on string
2. Error: Call to a member function fetch() on string

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = $_POST["query"];
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `name` LIKE :search;");
    $query->bindValue(':search','%'.$search.'%');
    $query->execute();
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id";
}

//if($query->rowCount() > 0) ---- this also doesn't work
if($query) {
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $output .= 'TEST';
    }
    echo $output;
} else {
    echo 'Data Not Found';
}
```

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM ...` if the code follows this path, then `$query` is a string, hence the error. What was the idea with that `else` clause...are you intending to execute that query at some point?

Comment: I want something like this...when a user search for a product it should get the list of matched items or else nothing should be shown.

Comment: Solved thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably rather alike that:

```
if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = $_POST["query"];
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `name` LIKE :search;");
    $query->bindValue(':search','%'.$search.'%');

} else {
    /* not overwriting variable $query with a SQL string in here: */
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id;"); "";
}
$query->execute();
```

Comment: This works, thanks. As this is for live search, the default div contains all the products on page and not after an input.